# Error in select query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I've used a select statement in stored procedure in oracle 11g xe.But an error is showing as

```
pls-00428-an INTO clause is expected with select statement
```

I just cannot understand the error.When i searched i found out that in pl/sql an into clause is needed.I'm using toad.But when i used sql editor same error is showing.

Here's my procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ACTSINFO.sp_Get_WorkDetails
IS
BEGIN
 select * from workdetails;
END sp_Get_WorkDetails;
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle is different from Microsoft SQL Server and therefor returning a result set from a procedure (or function) is different as well.

What you are looking for is a "pipelined table function".

Please refer to the manual for a description and an example:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/tuning.htm#i53109

Here are some more examples from other sites:

http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=207
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/PipelinedTableFunctions.php
http://psoug.org/reference/pipelined.html

Comment: @Sathy: yes it would, but I find a table function much easier to handle as you can simply run `select * from table(my_function())`. Not all programming languages handle ref cursors well

Comment: Indeed, wanted to hear your thoughts on why a pipelined function over ref cursor. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to write *wrong* syntax or *improper* use of SELECT statement. You have to either create a [cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10767/procedures_plsql.htm) or use [SELECT .. INTO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm) syntax to set scalar value to the local variables.

Comment: I'm not familiar with oracle.Can you please show how to write procedure with select..into syntax with respect to above procedure

Comment: @ksg - Have a look at post. I've pasted oracle doc link.

Comment: Here the problem is i want to get all the data in the form of datatable.If i write a select.. into statement could i get all the data in the form of datatable